# Green function of the Laplace-Dirichlet operator in a bounded domain

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, $d = 1,2,3$, be a bounded domain with $\partial \Omega$ smooth. Let $$A = -\Delta \colon H_0^1(\Omega) \cap H^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$$be the Laplace-Dirichlet operator. I am looking for a reference that assures the existence of a Green operator for $A$, namely $G \colon L^2(\Omega) \to H_0^1(\Omega) \cap H^2(\Omega)$ such that $$v = Gf \Longleftrightarrow Av = f.$$

In addition, what do we know about it? I am particularly interested in compactness of this Green operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the problem of find $u\in H_0^1$ such that $$\tag{1}\int_\Omega\nabla u\nabla v=\int_\Omega fv,\ \forall\ v\in H_0^1$$

There is a lot of ways to solve this problems, to wit, one can use Lax-Milgram theorem or Calculus of Variation or Monotone Methods operators and so on. Let's try the second one (because I really like it more than others).

Define $I:H_0^1\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$I(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2-\int_\Omega fu$$

Note that $I$ is the energy functional associated to the problem $(1)$, i.e. $$\langle I'(u),v\rangle = \int_\Omega\nabla u\nabla v-\int_\Omega fv, \forall\ u,v\in H_0^1$$

where $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes duality between $H_0^1$ and $H^{-1}$. Hence, to solve $(1)$ is equivalently to find $u\in H_0^1$ such that $$\langle I'(u),v\rangle =0,\ \forall\ v\in H_0^1$$

The last equality is saying that $u$ is a critical point of $I$. Hence, let's try to find a critical point of $I$ (in fact a minimum point).

Note that (by using Holder and Poincare inequality) there exist a constant $C>0$ such that $$\tag{2}I(u)\geq \frac{1}{2}\|u\|_{1,2}^2-C\|u\|_{1,2}$$

From $(2)$ we conclude that $I$ is coercive ($I(u)\to\infty$ if $\|u\|_{1,2}\to\infty$). Now let's prove that $I$ is lower semicontinuous in the weak topology. Let $u_n\to u$ in the weak topology. On one hand we have that $\|\cdot\|_{1,2}$ is lower semicontinuous in the weak topology. On other hand, note that by the compact immersion of $H_0^1$ in $L^2$, we can suppose that (up to a subsequence) $u_n\to u$ strongly in $L^2$, hence, by using Lebesgue theorem, we can conclude that $\int_\Omega fu_n\to \int_\Omega fu$. Therefore $I$ is weak lower semicontinuous.

By using the fact that $I$ is coercive and weak lower semicontinuous, we can conclude that there exist $u\in H_0^1$ such that $I(u)\leq I(v)$ for every $v\in H_0^1$. Because $I$ is strictly convex, we also have that $u$ is unique, hence we can associate to $(1)$ the Solution operator or Green operator $G$, i.e. if $G(f)=u$ then $u$ satisfies $(1)$. Note that by regularizing the solution (see [Brezis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387709134) chapter 9) we can suppose that $u\in H_0^1\cap H^2$, therefore $$G:L^2\to H_0^1\cap H^2$$

The first thinkg we can cnote about $G$ is it's continuity: indeed, by taking $v=u=G(f)$ in $(1)$ we have by Holder and Poincare inequality that $$\|G(f)\|_{1,2}\leq C\|f\|_2$$

On the other hand, because $H_0^1\cap H^2$ is compactly embedded in $L^2$, we can conclude that $$G:L^2\to L^2$$

is a compact operator.

Remark: You can also show that $G$ is positive and symmetric.

Remark 1: All that I have said here can be found for example in: [Brezis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387709134) chapter 9, [Evans](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821849743) chapter 6 and so on...

Comment: what a great answer! definitely +1; before accepting it I'll take a few moments to reflect better on some step. In the meantime, thank you very much for the attention you gave to my question!

Comment: You are welcome @user01123581321345589144... If you need some more details, feel free to ask.

Comment: Ok, it's all clear! the only thing that I still have to study is the compactness of $H^1_0$ in $L^2$, which I suppose to be hold in any dimension.

Comment: Yes it is, in fact we have more, we have that $H_0^1$ is compactly embedded in $L^{2^\star}$, where $2^\star=\frac{2N}{N-2}$ for $N>2$ and for $N\leq2$ we have that $H_0^1$ is compactly embedded in $L^p$ for all $p\in [2^\star,\infty)$. As you can see, in the first case, $2^\star>2$, hence $L^{2^\star}$ is embedded in $L^2$. In the second case, you just take any $p>2$.

Comment: let's see if I understand correctly: if $N > 2$ it is not true that $H^1_0$ is compactly embedded into $L^{2^*}$(or at least it is not true from rellich kondrachov theorem) but the embedding is compact in any $L^q$, with $q < 2^*$ and $2$ is always smaller than $2^*$. I don't get the second case or, at least I don't recognize what theorem implies this; anyway I think that it is possible to find an argument that does not mention dimensions, maybe something like the Ascoli-Arzelà theorem (the boundedness of the $H^1_0$-norm tells a lot in this direction, I guess) Thank you again!

Comment: Let me try to explain it again i other words: If the domain is regular like yours then $H_0^1$ is compactly embedded in $L^{2^\star}$ for $N>2$. But $L^{2^\star}$ is continuously embedded in $L^2$, so $H_0^1$ is compactly embedded in $L^2$. When $N=2$, $H_0^1$ is compactly embedded in $L^p$ for $p\in [2^\star,\infty)$, but by the same argument we conclude that $H_0^1$ is compactly embedded in $L^2$ for $N=2$. For $N=1$, $H_0^1$ is compactly embedded in $C(\overline{\Omega})$ and again, $H_0^1$ is comapctly embedded in $L^2$ because $C(\overline{\Omega})$ is continuously embedded in $L^2$.

Comment: When dealing with Sobolev immersion, one always has to consider 3 case, for instance, if we want to know where the space $W^{1,p}$ is embedded, we have to consider the cases: $N>p$, $N=p$ and $N<p$. THe result here is similar to the last one. Hence immersion does indeed need to take into account dimension.

Comment: everything is crystal clear! thank you again! :D